# Responsive breakpoints going from LESS to SASS

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, less, mixins

I'm trinyg to adjust from less to sass.

I have responsive break-points defination in less variables:

```
/* Breakpoints */
@break1:~"(max-width: 570px)";
@break2:~"(min-width: 571px) and (max-width: 1002px)";
@break3:~"(min-width: 1003px)";
```

and components that using them this way:

```
    /*component*/
    .main-header{
        /*base styles - all devices*/

        /*responsive breakpoints for component*/
        @media @break1{
            /*mobile only (from 0px up top 570px)*/
        }

        @media @break2{ 
                /*tablet only (from 571px up top 1002px)*/
        }
        @media @break3{
            /*desktop only (from 1003px up infinite)*/
        }
        @media @break2, @break3{
            /*tablet & desktop (from 571px up infinite)*/
        }
    }
```

I Saw that there is other way in SASS to do reponsive design break-ponits, but neihther way doesn't achive using two breakponits together like in this example in less:

```
        @media @break2, @break3{
            /*tablet & desktop (from 571px up infinite)*/
        }
```

I search for solution that achieve using multiple breakponits together, without adding a new breakpoints.

[VIEW DEMO](http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/emGQpE)

Answer (score -1):

replace comma with and- `@media $break2 and $break3 {}`

also you cant store strings in variables, you either need to create mixin or update your code to something like this

```
/* Breakpoints */
$break1: 570px;
$break2: 571px;
$break3: 1003px;

/*CODE EXAMPLE - for component header  + include responsive*/

        .main-header{
            /*base styles - all devices*/
            height:20px;            

            /*responsive breakpoints for component*/
          @media only screen and (max-width : $break2) and (min-width: $break3) {

            }
        }
```

this will give you `@media (min-width: 571px) and (max-width: 1002px) and (min-width: 1003px)`

more appropriate solution would be nice css structure: don't use breakpoints like in sample, but override them, start styling for all viewports (generaly for desktop), then move to tablet viewports with `@media (max-width : 1024px)` and override desktop styles with changes for tablet, and finally move to mobile viewports overriding desktop and tablet sizes, in this way you need less code, since some properties already comes from desktop styling and you need only to override the ones you need to change

Comment: It doesn't work - http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/zxEMvp